# How can I see if/what income/current account payment data is gathered by credit referencing agencies?

Tags: united-kingdom, income, checking-account

According to two [Telegraph article](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/personal-banking/current-accounts/how-your-bank-spies-on-your-exact-monthly-income---and-shares-it/)s:

[Almost all of Britain's banks now record most current account customers' monthly incoming payments. This is distributed monthly to credit reference agencies](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/personal-banking/current-accounts/90pc-of-bank-customers-unaware-their-income-details-are-tracked/) [..]

(And this is backed up by their marketing material, while this information is not shown in our traditional and fairly freely available credit reports/files.)

I would like to be able to keep an eye on this considering I have spotted several errors in my credit report (incidentally regarding payments!), which are difficult and time consuming to get corrected.

I would also be interested if anybody knows if this includes payments into pension plans and savings accounts? Thank you.

Comment: I would assume all incomings and outgoings are recorded. I believe overdrafts are what they might be more interested in, so I believe all transactions are recorded.